# Is the Solovay-Kitaev theorem relevant for modern hardware?

Tags: gate-synthesis, universal-gates, superconducting-quantum-computing, solovay-kitaev-algorithm, compiling

The Solovay-Kitaev theorem (and more recent improvements) explains how to efficiently compile any 2-qubit unitary into any universal (dense) *finite* set of gates. My question is if this theorem is relevant for modern hardware?

Take, for example, superconducting qubits. There, modulo noise and errors, *arbitrary* single-qubit gates can be executed. Having the capacity to perform arbitrary single-qubit gates allows to compile any 2-qubit gate with at most three CNOTs.

I am not sure, but I'm guessing that other hardware platforms also allow for the continuous single-qubit gates. Does this make the Solovay-Kitaev theorem obsolete for practical purposes, or am I missing something?

Comment: Note that you cannot perform any rotation. There is still a minimal angle you can use. The situation is similar to representation of real numbers on a classical computer. Althought they are called real, we only work with finite set of numbers as a memory is also finite.

Comment: @MartinVesely the minimal angles are due to errors, right? Say it's 1$^\circ$ error. Is it possible to get a smaller error, say 0.5$^\circ$, by using a combination of gates with $1^{\circ}$ eror?

Comment: No, but I meant that probably you could use combination of H and T gates (if they are native and not implemented with rotation gates) to reach a better accuracy, but this is only idea...maybe there is a flaw.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you'll find that most hardware, at the hardware level, gives you arbitrary single qubit rotations. So, in that sense, it is true that Solovay-Kitaev is not directly applicable to current systems. However, obsolete is certainly not the right word. It's rather the opposite - it's ahead of its time.

The importance of the Solovay-Kitaev algorithm is really once we start to do error correction (which requires bigger devices). When you implement an error correcting code, even if you have arbitrary single-qubit rotations at the physical level, you (generally) only have a finite gate set at the level of logical qubits. So to get an arbitrary rotation, you need Solovay-Kitaev or similar.

Comment: An analogous comment applies to topological quantum gates, some references on that point are listed here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Solovay-Kitaev+theorem#ReferencesInTopologicalQuantumComputation